# back button of browser issue in asp.net logout

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i click on logout button, everything will be fine after that click on back button of browser user does not enter or login ..thats also good.(but, no event click on master pages;  working is good  )

and, any event is clicked like search items (i mean  using select query or fetch data through button click)

logout button working not good ...its work like normal page ;i.e. when i click on logout ...redirect to home page using `Session.clear();` & `Redirect.Response("page.aspx")`

Use this code,behind master page page_load:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            if (Session["name"] == null)
            {

                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }

            else
            {

                Response.ClearHeaders();

                Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");

                Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

                Label1.Text = "WELCOME" + " " + Session["name"];


            }
```

now i want to disabling back button without using of javascript, because reason is when someone stop the javascript of browser ....same issues occurs..

Comment: question is messy, I would suggest to use this tricks http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 { 
// Put user code to initialize the page here 
if (Session["SessionId"] == null) { Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); } Response.Buffer=true; Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d); Response.Expires = -1500; Response.CacheControl ="no-cache"; }

Comment: Remove if (!IsPostBack) condition and check. Hopefully will work for you and and its also helpful to make your app more secure.

Comment: Refer this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/28458499/2089963

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Put user code to initialize the page here
        if (Session["SessionId"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); 
        }


        Response.Buffer=true;
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Expires = -1500;
        Response.CacheControl ="no-cache";

    }
```